# How can I find all arrays with the same values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with several arrays inside him, like that:

```
var arrs = [
  ['qqq', 5],
  ['www', 2],
  ['qqq', 15],
  ['qqq', 11],
  ['www', 1],
  ['eee', 22]
];
```

How can I find all arrays with the same values and sum them into one array, like that:

```
[
    ['qqq', 31],
    ['www', 3]
];
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? And what about `['eee', 22]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a new "results" array to store the output. Then loop you input array and either add to the results (if its a new one), or update the results if a match is found.

Something like this:

```
var arrs = [
    ['qqq', 5],
    ['www', 2],
    ['qqq', 15],
    ['qqq', 11],
    ['www', 1],
    ['eee', 22]
];

function sumDuplicates(arr) {
    var results = [];//array to hold the results
    //loop the input array so we can process each item
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var current = arr[i];//get the current item we are processing
        var match = null;//this will hold a match, IF we find one
        //loop the results to look for an existing match
        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
            var item = results[j];//get the item in the results that we want to check for match
            //check if we have found a match
            if (item[0] === current[0]) {
                match = item;//match found so store the match for later
                break;//match found so break the loop
            }
        }
        //no match found, so add the current item to the results (so it can be matched later)
        if (!match) results.push(current);
        //match found, so increment the stored value
        else match[1] = match[1] + current[1];
    }

    return results;
}

var result = sumDuplicates(arrs);
console.log(result);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cr4eM/)

Note that this will include non-duplicates too (such as `'eee'`), which makes sense to me. If you do for some reason need to remove items without duplicates then let me know